# MySQL migration Wizard

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, migration

I'm trying to migrate from MsSQL to MySQL using MySql Workbench 6.3 Migration wizard. And there're one issue with emoji string.

My MsSQL table contains column: Name nchar(30)

Let's say I have row with Name=N''.

Then I launch MySQL migration wizard and it fails on this row with error:

```
ERROR: `xxx2`.`TestTable`:Inserting Data: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x90\xA7  ...' for column 'Name' at row 1
```

How can I make wizard handle such string correct? Also it creates table with this type of column in my target db:

```
`Name` CHAR(30) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL
```

Comment: Check [Bug #87593: wbcopytables uses utf8 hardcoded and prevents migration of four-byte characters](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87593).

Comment: Yep, the same bug :( Looks like I need to find some other tool to migrate. Thanks!